# How to take difference of index values in php array

Tags: php, arrays, array-push

I have an array that looks like the following.

```php
Array (
  [0] => Array ([label] => 2020-04-01 11:44:13, [y] => 100)
  [1] => Array ([label] => 2020-04-01 11:45:49, [y] => 150)
  [2] => Array ([label] => 2020-04-01 13:11:24, [y] => 175)
  [3] => Array ([label] => 2020-04-02 10:19:08, [y] => 200)
  [4] => Array ([label] => 2020-04-02 11:24:38, [y] => 250)
  [5] => Array ([label] => 2020-04-04 12:24:38, [y] => 300)
  [6] => Array ([label] => 2020-04-05 13:49:38, [y] => 400)
  [7] => Array ([label] => 2020-04-05 14:36:38, [y] => 450)
  [8] => Array ([label] => 2020-04-05 14:24:38, [y] => 550)
  [9] => Array ([label] => 2020-04-08 09:20:41, [y] => 600)
  [10] => Array ([label] => 2020-04-08 10:09:38, [y] => 635)
  [11] => Array ([label] => 2020-04-08 11:35:33, [y] => 690)
  [12] => Array ([label] => 2020-04-08 13:24:38, [y] => 725)
  [13] => Array ([label] => 2020-04-08 17:12:35, [y] => 775)
)
```

As you can see, I have an array of 14 and each has two values `label` and `y` and I am passing them both as my chart data point.

Below is my code

```php
<?PHP
$dataPointskWh = array();
$dataPointskWhDiff = array();
$model = $dataProvider->getModels();

foreach ($model as $row) {
    // pushing for kwh values
    array_push($dataPointskWh, array(
        "label" => $row['Data_Date_Time'],
        "y" => $row['kWh']
    ));
}
?>
```

**What I want to do**

1. I want to make the difference in the following pattern `array[1][y] - array[0][y]` which gives me `50`, `array[2][y] - array[1][y]` which gives me `25` and up to so on till the end of array.
2. With that, I also want to make the difference between the date-time like `array[1][label]-array[2][label]`, `array[2][label]-array[1][label]` up to so on
3. Then I want to do this `array_push($dataPointskWhDiff, array("label"=>$row['Data_Date_Time'],"y"=>$row['kWh']));`
4. Finally I will pass it to my datapoints in chart `dataPoints: <?php echo json_encode($dataPointskWhdIFF, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK); ?>`

```php
foreach ($dataPointskWh as $key => $number) {
    if (isset($dataPointskWh[$key+1])) {
        $dataPointskWhDiff[$number] = $number - $dataPointskWh[$key+1];
    }
}

var_dump($dataPointskWhDiff);
die();
```

The error I am getting is `Unsupported operand types` at `$dataPointskWhDiff[$number] = $number - $dataPointskWh[$key+1];`

How can I achieve this? Any help would be highly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

**First of all, with this line you have 2 fundamental errors.** `$dataPointskWhDiff[$number] = $number - $dataPointskWh[$key+1];`

1. You are trying to push into array `$dataPointskWhDiff` value on position `$number` which is actually an array.

    
    *According to* [PHP docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php). 
   1.1 - **The key can either be an integer or a string.** 
   1.2 - **Arrays and objects can not be used as keys. Doing so will result in a warning: Illegal offset type.**
2. Your `$number` variable and `$dataPointskWh[$key+1]` key inside the `foreach` loop are obviously a type of `array`. You cannot use `-` operand with array types by doing the following `$number - $dataPointskWh[$key+1]`. That's why you caught `Fatal Error: Unsupported operand types in.` 
    
    [Here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.array.php) you can check valid `array operators`.

I think you are basically trying to achieve the following:

`$dataPointskWhDiff[$key] = $number['y'] - $dataPointskWh[$key+1]['y'];`

This will substract `y` value of next iteration `$dataPointskWh[$key+1]['y']` from current `$number`.

**JFYI:** Also I would suggest you to check boundaries and be careful with `$dataPointskWh[$key+1]` because during iterations you do not know if `$key + 1` exists in `$dataPointsKwh`.